# How to add scripts to pull requests to show due diligence of work

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm wondering if there is a workflow that allows developers to share due dilligence of work in a pull request.

To give you some insight, I noticed that if you have a network parameter in your config, like chain=main and then use chain=test in the commandline, you get an error message but It doesn't really tell you what is going on.

This change provides a little bit more verbosity letting the user know where and how the collision is happening.

For example, my change breaks the test
util_tests/util_ChainMerge

You can run it as per the instructions
`CHAIN_MERGE_TEST_OUT=results.txt {build_dir}/src/test/test_bitcoin --run_test=util_tests/util_ChainMerge`

an excerpt for an example

Current:

```
 -regtest=1 -noregtest=1 noregtest=1 notestnet=1 || main
 -regtest=1 -noregtest=1 testnet=1 regtest=1 || error: Invalid combination of -regtest, -signet, -testnet and -chain. Can use at most one.
```

Mine with a more verbose error message:

```
 -regtest=1 -noregtest=1 noregtest=1 notestnet=1 || main
 -regtest=1 -noregtest=1 testnet=1 regtest=1 || error: Invalid combination of -regtest, -signet, -testnet and -chain. Can use at most one./n Too many network flags being set in the commandline.
```

So I would like to show that I have a script that compares these results appropriately and shows that my change doesn't break anything.

What is the best way to package helper scripts up to help reviewers? Should I make a separate repo for reference?

Answer (score 1):

Some answers I got from irc.

luke-jr:
Kaizen_Kintsugi_: if they're short enough, I've seen them inlined in ``` blocks

Earnestly:
Kaizen_Kintsugi_: If I ever have to dump a large log, I use a  element.  So name of log *newline* ``` ... ``` *newline*  -> blank lines are important for ```